# Rails: Automatically assign parameters in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, controller, attributes

I'm creating a Rails app which allows users to create different animals and assign them attributes.

One of the attributes they an assign is "range". There are currently four types of ranges and each range has a different id:

```
land - id:1
sea - id:2
air - id:3
underground - id:4
```

Range has its own controller, model, and view in my app.

Each animal can be created with an id, a name, and a range. But I also have a column entitled range_id, which is what I am using to tie the animal back to the range.

```
{name:"cat", range:"land"}
#ids are assigned automatically
```

For views/animals/new.html.erb, I include a form that asks for each animal's attributes.

```
<h1> Add Animal </h1>

<%= form_for :animal, url: animals_path do |f| %>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :name %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :range %> <br>
    <%= f.select :range, ['land', 'sea', 'air', 'underground'], :prompt => 'Select One' %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <p>
    <% end %>
```

My problem is, I need to automatically assign a range_id to each new Animal based on the range. So, if a user created "whale" with a range "sea", that Animal also needs to have a range_id of 2.

How can I do this automatic assignment? Here is my current animal_params method in animals_controller.rb:

```
private def animal_params
    params.require(:animal).permit(:id, :name, :range, :range_id)
  end
```

Should range_id be included there, or what would be the easiest way to alter it automatically?

Comment: `:range` is not needed in permitted params to go with answer provided by Emu.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an answer in the documentation [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) - you shouldn't be hardcoding these values into your view, and should instead be using ActiveRecord to populate the values for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= f.select :range_id, options_for_select(Range.all.collect { |range| [range.name, range.id]}, f.object.range_id), {}, class: 'form-control', include_blank: 'Please Select' %>
```

You can get the reference from [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select). 
I assume that you have a model named `Range` which has two attributes - name, id. The select box above will show all the ranges in the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.